# Laravel's email verification redirecting to login page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, email-verification

I am having a problem with Laravel 5.7 Email verification.

After using Laravel's email verification it is forcing me to the login page if I'm not logged in.

Here is what we need: 
We enable the code for the email verification of users. So when someone signup we want to verify the user email. We want the user to signup on the website, the user is asked to verify the email address and they can't do anything further until verified - which is ok for me.

Our trouble is, if a new user comes (Not registered) to our website, our website will force all that user to the login page as well .

A normal user who is not signed up is also getting to login page and force to verify or log in.

While we want the only user who signed up needs to verify. Which is working.

All the normal users who are not subscribed can use site easy. Where currently they are going to login page

What I've done so far
Added the following code

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('profile', function () { })->middleware('verified');
```

After Verifying Emails

```
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
```

It is working fine but,

What I need is that I don't want to force users to verify email because this is blocking the user from accessing the home page of my website.

Comment: what is the route for your home page? is seems that perhaps you are requiring the user to be authenticated to see this page?

Comment: This is my home page route Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home');

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you need to specify what pages will use auth middleware. To exclude your welcome view.

In your controller file.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')->except('welcome');
}

public function home(){
    return view('welcome');
}
```

Im using 'welcome' view, because I believe that you do not change the code of default Laravel installation, you must be careful, since the view 'home' is the default page that laravel shows after you logged in. If you remove the authentication layer of that page, any user can access your system. You must change the code of this page or create another view.

In your web.php file

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home');
```

[Laravel Docs - Controller Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#controller-middleware)

Answer (score 0):

try to add except method and check for url home

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->except('home');
}
```

Comment: thanks, @guruprasad I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home'); and sorry @guruprasad this is not working as a new user is still redirecting to the /login when they are trying to access /